# ffmpeg batch script that combines multiple audio clips with one image > mp4

Tags: batch-file, audio, ffmpeg

I found this script in another thread and edited it to make this:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.jpg) do (
   if exist "%%~nF.mp3" ( 
      ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "%%~nF.jpg" -i "%%~nF.mp3" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec mpeg4 -shortest "%%~nF.mp4" 
   ) 
)
```

It combines all mp3 files with all jpeg files that share the same filename into a mp4 video with the static image running.

But the problem is - if I want to convert more than one mp3 file using the same image (let's say three mp3s), I have to duplicate the same jpeg image three times!

For example, if I have three Michael Jackson mp3 files:

```
MJ1.mp3
MJ2.mp3
MJ3.mp3
```

I would need to create:

```
MJ1.jpg
MJ2.jpg
MJ3.jpg
```

But really I only need one image for all three mp3s.

What edits do I need to make to the script combine all mp3s with one jpeg file? Let's say I wanted every mp3 file in the folder to convert with `default.jpg`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert the loop. Instead of iterating over the images, iterate over the sound files.

```dos
@echo off
for %%F in (*.mp3) do (
      ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "default.jpg" -i "%%~nxF" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec mpeg4 -shortest "%%~nF.mp4" 
)
```